# Text Rendering Mode with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, documentation, pdfbox

I am trying to apply "text rendering mode invisible" by using PDFBox. I write this code but i don't know how to continue even how to call the process function in order to set the text invisible in the document.
Any reply appreciated.

```
    public class Test1 extends OperatorProcessor{
    private static final String src="...";
    private static PDFStreamEngine pp;
    private static PDPageContentStream content;
    private static PDType1Font font; 
    public static void CreatePdf(String src) throws IOException, COSVisitorException{
    PDRectangle rec= new PDRectangle(400,400);
    PDDocument document= null;
    document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(rec);
    document.addPage(page);
    PDDocumentInformation info=document.getDocumentInformation();
    info.setAuthor("PdfBox");
    info.setCreator("Pdf");
    info.setSubject("Stéganographie");
    info.setTitle("Stéganographie dans les documents PDF");
    info.setKeywords("Stéganographie, pdf");
    content= new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
    pp=new PDFStreamEngine();
    font= PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    String texte="hello";
    content.beginText();
    content.setFont(font, 12);
    content.moveTextPositionByAmount(15, 385);           
    content.drawString(texte);
    content.endText();
    content.close();
    document.save("doc.pdf");
    document.close();       
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        // TODO code application logic here   
        Test1 tes= new Test1();
        tes.CreatePdf(src);
    }
    @Override
    public void process(PDFOperator pdfo, List<COSBase> list) throws IOException {
             COSNumber mode = (COSNumber)list.get(0);
            pp.getGraphicsState().getTextState().setRenderingMode(mode.intValue());
    }
}
```

Best regards,
Liszt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When going through the PDPageContentStream documentation at http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/, I have the feeling there is no explicit method for this (I can be wrong because I am not familiar with this product).

There is an appendRawCommands through, which seems a good escape. I would expect you would do something like this (not tested):

```
content.beginText();
content.setFont(font, 12);
content.moveTextPositionByAmount(15, 385);           
content.appendRawCommands("3 Tr ");
content.drawString(texte);
content.endText();
```